# Making Snowpack work with Babel, "require is not defined". Am I missing a require transformation?

Tags: javascript, babeljs, snowpack

I'm approaching Snowpack, previously used Webpack + Babel loader. I'm missing something and I know what: some **sort of `require` polyfill or transformation**. I don't know the internals of Webpack that make `require` work in the browser, but I can't get the same with Snowpack.

In my `snowpack.config.json` I'm loading the Babel plugin:

```json
{
  "buildOptions": {
    "clean": true,
    "out": "dist"
  },
  "mount": {
    "src": "/"
  },
  "plugins": [
    "@snowpack/plugin-babel"
  ]
}
```

My `.babelrc` is using `@babel/preset-env`:

```json
{
  "presets": [
    ["@babel/preset-env", {
      "corejs": 3,
      "useBuiltIns": "usage"
    }]
  ]
}
```

A test script is transformed using `snowpack build` into this:

```js
"use strict";

require("core-js/modules/es.array.concat");

require("core-js/modules/es.array.map");

// Import polyfill
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  [1, 2, 3].concat([4, 5]).map(function (n) {
    return console.log(n);
  });
});

window.addEventListener('load', function () {});
```

(The problem, of course, is that `require` is not defined)

Comment: webpack won't keep transpiled files as-is, instead it will bundle them together. I also couldn't get this working with snowpack. I'd expect it to work with `targets.esmodules: true` settings OR without `preset-env`... No luck either way!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Babel still transpiles `import` statements to `require` with your config. In order to prevent this try the following configuration:

```json
{
  "presets": [
    ["@babel/preset-env", {
      "targets": {
        "esmodules": true
      },
      "modules": false
    }]
  ]
}
```

You can extend it with your additional settings, but this should be a minimal working setup.

As I mentioned in comments, without `modules: false` it still can transpile to `require` statements, so you have to override default behavior [as per docs](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-env#modules)